# How to find current user within model in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table for messages and another table for messageviews.  I'm looking to show unread messages to an individual user.  With my message table, I've sent up a new field that looks to see if any messageviews exist for the current message.  If they do, then my Viewed bool should return true otherwise false(if they haven't viewed the message).  Everything works fine, except that I'm unable to find the currently logged in user with User.Identity.GetUser() as I normally would.  I've added the correct usings as well.  Is there some limitation within a model to restrict this type of call.  If so, how can I find the current user within a model?

```
    public bool Viewed
    {
        get
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            //var _userId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); 
            var _userId = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.GetUserId();
            List<MessageView> m_List = db.MessageView.Where(u => u.UserId == _userId && u.MessageId == O_MessageId).ToList();
            var count = m_List.Count();
            if (count >= 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Resolved:  Outside of a controller you can find the current user with this -

var _userId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

Comment: Are you using Async methods? Can you show some of your code to see if we can help you better?

Comment: Try with `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.GetUserId()`

Comment: I get the error, thread does not exist in the current context.  I've added my check above.

Comment: The thread user is typically the account IIS is running as unless you're using impersonation. You would probably need to pass some additional data down to your model (either the HttpContext (bad) or the User Id from the calling controller).

Comment: hm.. how can you call a controller from a model?

Comment: Figured it out -  thanks for the help -  outside of a controller you need this:  var _userId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

Comment: Yeah, that's not ideal within your model however - you're tying that explicitly to the HttpContext, which may not exist. You should look at a way to pass in the user ID to the model as you construct it, or use a method rather than a property to determine if the user has viewed it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into other options further.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of a controller you can find the current user with this:
var _userId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

Comment: dont forget to include using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;